# facebook, google+ share button does not recognize my meta tags

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-plus, facebook-social-plugins

I have a Google+ and Facebook Like button on my page. i have the required scripts from them and setting the data attribute dynamically.  BUT when i click on share button OR Like button it opens up with a random image and title. I have the meta tags for them to recognize Title, Image and description i would like to use BUT somehow they are not picking up meta tags.

## Here is the Errors from Facebook Developer Debug Tool

```
fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
```

## Rendered Meta Tags in HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" 
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <meta content="No appointment necessary. We hear you coming" name="og:title">
    <meta content="http://www.mysite.com" name="og:site_name">
    <meta content="blog" name="og:type">
    <meta content="http://www.mysite.com/entries/viewentry.aspx" name="og:url">
    <meta content="http://static.mysite.com/Images/imag21.jpg" name="og:image">
    <meta content="447438772019226" name="fb:app_id">
    <meta content="Temp title and some descriptions" name="description">
```

## Facebook Scripts

```
<div class="facebookShare">
        <div class="fb-like" data-font="verdana" data-href=
        '<%= currentPageURL.Value %>' data-layout="box_count" data-send="true"
        data-show-faces="true" data-width="500"></div>
    </div>

// currentPageURL is a hidden field which sets the URL fine.

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

## Google+ Share Button Script

```
<div class="googlePlusShare col span_1_of_12">
        <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
        <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation=
       "vertical-bubble" data-height="60" data-href='<%= currentPageURL.Value %>'</div>
    </div>

(function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script');
      po.type = 'text/javascript';
      po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
```

## Rendered HTML for Both

```
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"
    data-font="verdana" data-href="http://www.mysite.com/viewentry.aspx?entryId=6"
    data-layout="box_count" data-send="false" data-show-faces="true"
    data-width="500">
    </div>
```

// Google+ replaces the entire html and my `data-href` attribute as well and put some code in there in which i dont see my current page URL. Atleast i can see that in facebook tags

However, BOTH when clicked does not pull my meta tags information. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading your URL in: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets This will tell you if your URL is visible to Google.  It will also tell you if there are any errors in your markup.